# Collapse/expand rows in section

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that is grouped into three successive categories in a grouping scheme like this:

[image]

So the overall group "OCM" is broken down into subgroups named "N/A", "Financials", "Industrials" etc, each of which are broken up into further subgroups.

I have the same data in Excel, but unfortunately it is automaticlally formatted like this:

[image]

Instead of grouping the sections, everything has been expanded out and there is just a space to indicate where a new subgroup begins.

The data extends for several thousand rows, so grouping it by hand is impossible. Is there another way to group the data automatically, where a space indicates a subgroup?

EDIT

```
Function indenture(r As Range) As Integer
indenture = r.IndentLevel
End Function
```

Then  `nodeOrd = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).IndentLevel` returns the correct indent level.

Comment: Would you like a VBA solution for it?

Comment: Yes please, that would be perfect

Comment: Two questions - Is the data in your excel in consistent order and is the spacing (which denotes groups and sub groups) also in consistent order?

Comment: The data is not in consistent order. For instance, at the largest grouping the first entry ("OCM") could have 6 subgroups, while the next entry could have 3 subgroups, etc. However, the spacing to denote groups is consistent: the largest group will have no spacing, the second grouping will always have indent = 1, and the smallest grouping will have indent = 2, for all entries.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1 - Using groups**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Sheet1
        Dim i As Long, varLast As Long

        .Cells.ClearOutline
        varLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight 'helper column

        For i = 1 To varLast
            .Range("A" & i) = .Range("B" & i).IndentLevel
        Next

        Dim rngRows As Range, rngFirst As Range, rngLast As Range, rngCell As Range, rowOffset As Long

        Set rngFirst = Range("A1")
        Set rngLast = rngFirst.End(xlDown)
        Set rngRows = Range(rngFirst, rngLast)

        For Each rngCell In rngRows
            rowOffset = 1

            Do While rngCell.Offset(rowOffset) > rngCell And rngCell.Offset(rowOffset).Row <= rngLast.Row
                rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
            Loop

            If rowOffset > 1 Then
                Range(rngCell.Offset(1), rngCell.Offset(rowOffset - 1)).EntireRow.Group
            End If
        Next

        .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**Solution 2 - In case you don't want to modify the workbook data - workaround**

Step 1 - Create a `UserForm` and add `TreeView` Control

[image]

Step 2 - Add the following code in the `UserForm` code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.TreeView1
        .Style = tvwTreelinesPlusMinusText
        .LineStyle = tvwRootLines
    End With

    Call func_GroupData
End Sub

Private Sub func_GroupData()
    varRows = CLng(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    With Me.TreeView1.Nodes
        .Clear

        For i = 1 To varRows
            nodeTxt = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
            nodeOrd = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).IndentLevel
            nodeTxt = Trim(nodeTxt)
            nodeAmt = Trim(CStr(Format(Sheet1.Range("B" & i), "###,###,###,##0.00")))

            Select Case nodeOrd
                Case 0 'Level 0 - Root node
                    nodeTxt = nodeTxt & Space(80 - Len(nodeTxt & nodeAmt)) & nodeAmt
                    .Add Key:="Node" & i, Text:=Trim(nodeTxt)
                    nodePar1 = "Node" & i
                Case 1 'Level 1 node
                    nodeTxt = nodeTxt & Space(80 - Len(nodeTxt & nodeAmt)) & nodeAmt
                    .Add Relative:=nodePar1, Relationship:=tvwChild, Key:="Node" & i, Text:=Trim(nodeTxt)
                    nodePar2 = "Node" & i
                Case 2 'Level 2 node
                    nodeTxt = nodeTxt & Space(80 - Len(nodeTxt & nodeAmt)) & nodeAmt
                    .Add Relative:=nodePar2, Relationship:=tvwChild, Key:="Node" & i, Text:=Trim(nodeTxt)
                    nodePar3 = "Node" & i
            End Select

        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Step 3 - Add the following code in `ThisWorkbook` to show the treeview

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

The result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for coming up with a great workaround. I can't seem to get the code to work however - the categories aren't grouped together and just appear in a list when I run the script.

Comment: the nodeOrd part of the code seems to return  "0" for all values

Comment: I have assumed that there are 4 spaces before level1 and 8 before level2. Perhaps you need to adjust your spacing

Comment: what does nodeTxt  return for you ... check in debug.print

Comment: It correctly reads "nodeTxt" and "nodeAmt" as OCM and 45,727xx. The issue is that there technically aren't readable spaces, it's an indent (Format cells > Alignment > Indent = 1). There's a function that can return the correct nodeOrd (please see edit), and this works in your code

Comment: @beeba - modified the code to use indent instead of spaces... check if it works

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Would it be possible to export the TreeView control to a sheet in the excel workbook, keeping the node groupings intact?

Comment: Nop. Can't do that. But the data can be exported in XML format.

Comment: how do I export it in XML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133119/discussion-between-pankaj-jaju-and-beeba).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to add a button to each cell and to hide its children rows on *collapse* and display its children rows on *expand*.

Each `Excel.Button` executes one common method `TreeNodeClick` where the `Click` method is called on corresponding instance of `TreeNode`. The child rows are hidden or displayed based on the actual caption of the button.

At the beginning the source data range needs to be selected when the method `Main` is executed. Problem is that the collection of Tree-Nodes needs to be filled each time the sheet is opened. So the method `Main` needs to be executed when the sheet is opened othervise it won't work.

---

*Standard Module Code:*

```
Option Explicit

Public treeNodes As VBA.Collection

Sub Main()
    Dim b As TreeBuilder
    Set b = New TreeBuilder
    Set treeNodes = New VBA.Collection
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    b.Build Selection, treeNodes
End Sub

Public Sub TreeNodeClick()
    Dim caller As String
    caller = Application.caller
    Dim treeNode As treeNode
    Set treeNode = treeNodes(caller)
    If Not treeNode Is Nothing Then
        treeNode.Click
    End If
End Sub
```

---

*Class Module TreeNode:*

```
Option Explicit

Private m_button As Excel.Button
Private m_children As Collection
Private m_parent As treeNode
Private m_range As Range
Private Const Collapsed As String = "+"
Private Const Expanded As String = "-"
Private m_indentLevel As Integer

Public Sub Create(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal parent As treeNode)
On Error GoTo ErrCreate

    Set m_range = rng
    m_range.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25
    m_indentLevel = m_range.IndentLevel
    Set m_parent = parent
    If Not m_parent Is Nothing Then _
        m_parent.AddChild Me
    Set m_button = rng.parent.Buttons.Add(rng.Left + 3 + 19 * m_indentLevel, rng.Top + 3, 19, 19)
    With m_button
        .Caption = Expanded
        .Name = m_range.Address
        .OnAction = "TreeNodeClick"
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = False
    End With

    With m_range
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Value = Strings.Trim(.Value)
        .Value = Strings.String((m_indentLevel + 11) + m_indentLevel * 5, " ") & .Value
    End With

    Exit Sub

ErrCreate:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "TreeNode::Create"
End Sub

Public Sub Collapse(ByVal hide As Boolean)
    If hide Then
        m_range.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    m_button.Caption = Collapsed
    Dim ch As treeNode
    For Each ch In m_children
        ch.Collapse True
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Expand(ByVal unhide As Boolean)
    If unhide Then
        m_range.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    m_button.Caption = Expanded
    Dim ch As treeNode
    For Each ch In m_children
        ch.Expand True
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub AddChild(ByVal child As treeNode)
    m_children.Add child
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_children = New VBA.Collection
End Sub

Public Sub Click()
    If m_button.Caption = Collapsed Then
        Expand False
    Else
        Collapse False
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Get IndentLevel() As Integer
    IndentLevel = m_indentLevel
End Property

Public Property Get Cell() As Range
    Set Cell = m_range
End Property
```

---

*Class Module TreeBuilder:*

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Build(ByVal source As Range, ByVal treeNodes As VBA.Collection)
    Dim currCell As Range
    Dim newNode As treeNode
    Dim parentNode As treeNode
    For Each currCell In source.Columns(1).Cells
        Set parentNode = FindParent(currCell, source, treeNodes)
        Set newNode = New treeNode
        newNode.Create currCell, parentNode
        treeNodes.Add newNode, currCell.Address
    Next currCell
End Sub

Private Function FindParent(ByVal currCell As Range, ByVal source As Range, ByVal treeNodes As VBA.Collection) As treeNode
    If currCell.IndentLevel = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Integer
    Set c = currCell
    For r = currCell.Row - 1 To source.Rows(1).Row Step -1
        Set c = c.offset(-1, 0)
        If c.IndentLevel = currCell.IndentLevel - 1 Then
            Set FindParent = treeNodes(c.Address)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

---

*Result:*

[image]